# añadir script a perfil con api php para mikrotik

Tags: php, api, script

estoy empezando a trabajar con la API de Mikrotik, pero tengo un problema a la hora de querer agregar un perfil al hotspot, mediante PHP

```
    <?php 
    include_once('config/routeros_api.class.php');

    $API = new routeros_api();  
        $ip="192.15.10.1";
        $user="API";
        $pass="";
    $API->connect($ip, $user, $pass);

    $onlogin = ":local thoras 0";
$onlogin .="\n";
$onlogin .=":local atime [ /system clock get time ]";


    $ARRAY = $API->comm("/ip/hotspot/user/profile/add",  
            array( 
                "name"  => "Perfil Generado por PHP",
                "session-timeout" => '1h',
                "on-login" => $onligin ,
            )
        );
    echo "Perfil Generado.";
     ?>
```

pero por alguna razón el texto se corta, no reconoce el salto de linea, incluso si lo pongo de esta manera

```
$onlogin = ":local thoras 0 \n :local atime [ /system clock get time ]";
```

el texto se corta y solo lo inyecta hasta antes de \n